# How to get generic type and let the following code run?

Tags: typescript, generics

How to get generic type and let the following code run?

```
class ServiceRepository implements IServiceCollection {
    private col = new A4Lib.Collections.Dictionary<any, any>();

    public addSingleton<T>(service:T) {
        this.col.setValue(<T>service, service);
    }

    public getService<T>(): T {

        if (this.col )
        {
            return <T>this.col.getValue(T); //error 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript has a process called "type erasure" that means type information is removed during compilation. That means type annotactions, interfaces, type arguments, and generics don't exist at runtime.

You would have to implement your code so it could switch on something concrete at runtime, a simple answer would be to use a string name:

```
class ServiceRepository implements IServiceCollection {
    private col = new A4Lib.Collections.Dictionary<string, any>();

    public addSingleton<T>(name, service: T) {
        this.col.setValue(name, service);
    }

    public getService<T>(name: string): T {
        if (this.col) {
            return <T>this.col.getValue(name); //error 
        }
    }
}
```